# Apk tool Decode error during publish Smartface app studio

Tags: smartface.io

I want to publish my application but I am receiving error during Publish. Do see the 'Error' screenshot but java environment path is given. Do see the  'Java Environment Path' screenshot

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxD9N.png)

[Java Environment Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwOUq.png)

Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this :

1. Click WIN + R
2. Then enter apktool
3. Delete all files

and the above step's worked.

Answer (score 0):

Mine solved after restart computer!

Comment: Mine did't but I did use the above method and it solved it.